# Change List control scroll bar color in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I am able to change the list control scrollbar colour in MFC but the not able to change the colour of corner where vertical and horizontal scroll bar meet:

[image]

Comment: We don't know, what scrollbars you are using. [There are two types of scrollbars](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040510-00/?p=39413).

Comment: I am using the default scroll bar which is with clistctrl

Comment: How did you change the background color of the scrollbars in the CListCtrl?